# How to apply styles to TabPane in new Antd Tabs component

Tags: reactjs, tabs, components, antd, code-cleanup

This is my old implementation of the Tabs component in Ant Design.

```
const tabList = [
  {
    key: "tab1",
    label: "Tab1",
    children: <Tab1 />,
  },
  {
    key: "tab2",
    label: "Tab2",
    children: <Tab2 />,
  },
];

<Tabs onChange={onTabChange} activeKey={selectedTab}>
  {tabList.map((tab) => {
    const { key, label, children } = tab;
    return (
      <Tabs.TabPane
        key={key}
        tab={label}
        style={{ margin: "1.5rem auto 1.5rem" }}
      >
        {children}
      </Tabs.TabPane>
    );
  })}
</Tabs>;
```

In the new [version](https://ant.design/components/tabs/) ( > 4.23.0 ) the boilerplate got reduced.

I can simply pass my tabList to my Tabs as a prop `items`.

The new code looks something like this.

```
<Tabs items={tabList} />
```

But I had an issue with styling.

I am adding top and bottom margins to all of my TabPane components.

To get that margin in the new implementation. I had to do something like this.

```
  {
    key: "tab1",
    label: "Tab1",
    children: <Tab1 style={{margin: "1.5rem 0 1.5rem"}} />,
  },
```

Here I am facing two issues.

1. I need to add this for all my tabs in the tabList
2. I need to have a div in every component spreading the props that are passed above.

```
function Tab1(props) {
  return <div {...props}>JSX for original Tab1</div>;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Higher order component can solve this issue

Use a higher Order component like `<TabPaneWrapper>` or `<TabChildrenWrapper>`. This component does nothing but to wrap your children (`<TabPane>`) with a div and give the styles you require.

Component:

```
export function TabPaneWrapper({
  children,
  ...props
}){

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "1.5rem auto 1.5rem" }} {...props}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
const tabList = [
  {
    key: "tab1",
    label: "Tab1",
    children: <TabPaneWrapper> <Tab1 /> </TabPaneWrapper>,
  },
  {
    key: "tab2",
    label: "Tab2",
    children: <TabPaneWrapper> <Tab2 /> </TabPaneWrapper>,
  },
];
```

If you have more tabs or use this tabs component in multiple places. You will find TabPaneWrapper to be repetitive. In such case,

1. You can create a custom Tabs component like `<CustomTabs/>` which takes the tabList mentioned in the question.
2. Instead of wrapping every tab in the tabList with `<TabPaneWrapper/>`. You can loop this list inside the `<CustomTabs/>` component to generate the tabList mentioned above and then pass it to the Ant Desing `<Tabs/>` component.